# 404 error when accessing product or category url key from another store view

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a multilingual website with several store views. Let's say "English" and "French" ...

For years I used the same URL key for both store views. Last week I decided to change the URL keys for the French store. This results in 404 errors in Google Webmaster Tools, since Googlebot is trying to access the French URLs on the English store.

So before the change, I had this:

```
English: http://www.example.com/a-product.html
French: http://www.example.com/a-product.html?=___store=french
```

Then I had the brilliant idea to change my URLs as follows:

```
English: http://www.example.com/some-product.html
French: http://www.example.com/un-produit.html
```

Everything works fine from a user experience. You can switch back and forth between the English and French versions just fine.

However, Googlebot is not able to access the French store using the new URL keys. This results in a lot of 404 errors in Webmaster Tools.

So is there a correct way to implement multilingual URLs? Or should I give up and revert back to my original setup?

I'm using Magento 1.7.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

- Truncate core_url_rewrite table
- Delete old sitemap
- Reindex
- Generate new sitemap
- Login to Google webmaster tools account
- Submit newly created sitemap.

I hope this process will fix the error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that does not solve the issue.